# How can I performed an interpolation in one of the columns of a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate some values corresponding to a correction factor (Fp) for a variable called "W".

So, I have a file with Fp for certain "W" (the file has only two variables) and other file that needs Fp values for other "W" values (this file has seven variables including "W").

My idea was to merge the files and then run the function `approx()`. The merge went well, returning a file with 8 variables ( "W", "Fp", etc...). But when I tried to run `approx()`, the outcome was a list of length two. So, I'm thinking this is not the correct function. I wonder if I should use it as a function `approxfun()` but I'm not sure how.

This is my code:

```
muestra <- merge(corrfactor, flowersamp, by = "W", all = T)
```

The structure of my data frame is something like this:

[image: data frame table]

```
prueba <- approx(muestra$W, muestra$Fp, method = "linear")

class(prueba)
[1] "list"
length(prueba)
[1] 2
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please post data using `dput(muestra)`, not as an image.

Comment: In the data that you show,  you only have two values of Fp. You are not going to get a very accurate estimate of Fp from that.  for the data that you provide,  what more can you do than the line connecting the two points? `AF = function(W) { 0.99 + (W - 330) /10000 }`

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for all the answers. Someone pointed out to me that I was missing the xout argument in the function. After I added it the function worked. Also, I realized this function was not adequate for my data. What I need to do is a polynomial interpolation. Thanks again!